# Perl on asp.NET in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, web-services, perl, iis-7.5, activeperl

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm new to this kind of thing. I'm trying to set up a local dev environment to work on a web service that is going to be perl over asp.NET. I'm using windows 7 and IIS 7.5 to do this, and I've got Active State perl installed but I'm not sure how to get everything working.

I can run a .pl file off of a localhost and it works, but I don't know how to use perl within an .aspx page. From what I've seen it looks like I should just add:

```
<script language="PerlScript" runat="server">
```

but when I try to do that I'm getting the error:

> Parser Error Message: 'PerlScript' is not a supported language.

Do I have to add PerlScript as a language somewhere? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: So I ended up uninstalling perl and turning off IIS, then I turned back on IIS and reinstalled perl, but the 32 bit version this time. Then I used the command

`ap-iis-config add all`

which i found online to map the configurations to IIS. Tried again and it still wasn't recognizing PerlScript as a language so I did a little more digging and found a recommendation to turn on the 32 bit option for my site in IIS. Did that too and still didn't have any luck. So I did a bit more searching and then tried changing the filetype from .aspx to .asp and bingo! Such a stupid little fix that I wasted so much time on but I figured I'd add this in case anyone else finds themselves in the same situation. I'm not sure if all of the other steps were necessary but I think they may have been, I'll be going through the process again and figuring out exactly how to get it to work, but for now it seems turning on IIS then installing perl (32 bit), then mapping the perl extensions and turning on 32 bit mode in IIS seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

did you setup IIS to understand .pl and .plx files, not sure if that might help. if not try this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245225
I messed around with perl on my windows machine as well, set it up using the instructions provided and it worked fine, but i was running .pl and .plx files in iis, but doing it might help.

Comment: Yeah I've got it set up to work with .pl files (pointing to the perl executable) and like I said, those are working fine, and I've testing things running off .pl extensions, but I want to use perl within an .aspx page. All of the examples I've seen on the web say that you just have to set the language to 'PerlScript' but I'm getting an error when I try doing that.